# Where is the option to control property access spacing when formatting?

Tags: formatting, phpstorm, spacing

I'm almost sure that there used to be an option to control this formatting case:

```php
function __set( $k, $v ) {
    $this->values_input->{$k} = $v;
}
```

vs

```php
function __set( $k, $v ) {
    $this->values_input->{ $k } = $v;
}
```

I have a huge project that has the second case everywhere but when I try to format the code it removes the spaces around `$k`.

Has it been removed or am I missing something? I have almost all spacing cases checked in PhpStorm settings the few unchecked don't seem to be relevant.

Comment: I do not think there is any TBH (I see none in the latest stable 2022.3.3 version). I may only suggest to check `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Quality Tools` screen -- it has an option to use **external formatter** instead that _might do_ what you want: "PHP Code Beautifier and Fixer" or "PHP CS Fixer" -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.3/php-quality-tools.html#external_formatters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has never been such an option.
Here's the feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71891/Formatter-Allow-to-control-spaces-within-curly-braces-in-property-access

Comment: Huh, I suppose all those spaces are coming from NetBeans then